# Some basic questions about constructor and operators

Tags: c++, constructor, operators

Sorry if this question sounds too basic, but I'd like to know what EXACTLY happens in this code (`Point3d` is my own implementation):

```
int main()
{
    Point3d a(1,2,3);
    Point3d b(11,12,13);
    Point3d c = a+b;
    Point3d d = a;
    Point3d e;

    return 0;
}
```

So after running the code above, functions are called in the following order:

```
Point3d (const float x, const float y, const float z) // a
Point3d (const float x, const float y, const float z) // b
Point3d () //since I created a new object in operator+
operator+ (const Point3d& rhs) //a+b
Point3d (const Point3d& rhs) //the copy constructor for d = a
Point3d () //e
```

I noticed something:

1. no constructor is called for c
2. `operator=` is never called (However, if I put the assignment and instance declaration in different lines, `operator=` is called)

Is what I observed above expected? If so, why is `operator=` never called?

P.S. my operator+ is returning an object rather than an reference (Point3d rather than Point3d&), I think that's correct?

Comment: "*I'd like to know what EXACTLY happens in this code*" - that is what a debugger is for. Step through the code step by step to see EXACTLY what it does.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thanks for the suggestion! What I typed in the question is what I observed after using an debugger, I was not very confident with what I have seen--mainly operator= never called, hence the question.

Comment: As a general rule, a compiler will prefer a constructor with parameters over an assignment operator.

Comment: What's the return type of your `operator+`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl It's Point3d, it returns an object.

Answer (score 3):

> 1. no constructor is called for `c`

Most likely due to [Return Value Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

> 2. `operator=` is never called

Because none of the lines shown are performing assignments, only constructions. Use of `=` in a line that declares *and* assigns an object in the same statement is just "syntax sugar" for copy construction.

```
Point3d c = a+b; // aka: Point3d c(a+b);
Point3d d = a;   // aka: Point3d d(a);
```

> However, if I put the assignment and instance declaration in different lines, `operator=` is called

Yes, if separate statements (not lines) are used for declaration and assignment, then `operator=` is used.

Answer (score 0):

So there's a difference between a copy constructor and an assignment operator. 
Instances in which you call copy constructor:

```
object a = b
```

Instances in which you call an assignment operator:

```
object a;
object b;
a = b;
```